# What kind of date format is this 2013-07-03T15:00:00Z?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm seeing a date format like this `2013-07-03T15:00:00Z` and I wonder what it is. I need to create a date format like this from my list of dates and I don't know the meaning of T and Z.

The dates format is like this `2013-06-29 06:00:00` and I want to convert it to the format same as above.

Thanks.

Comment: Any help: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)?

Comment: ISO 8601 with time zone.

Answer (score 3):

You can read ISO 8601.
Or (shortened)...

- T is a delimiter between date and time and can be omitted.
- Z is designator for the UTC offset of 0 ('Zulu' time)